# Meteor installation error

Tags: meteor

I am facing problem while installing Meteor. Below is the snapshot of what I tried.

```
jakejacobs@jakejacobs-Peppy:~$ curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  6674    0  6674    0     0   3071      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--  3071
Downloading Meteor distribution
###############                                                           21.9%tar: .meteor/packages/coffeescript/.1.0.11.148kw9n++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileCoffeescript.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/generation/generators: Cannot utime: Not a directory
#################                                                         23.7%tar: .meteor/packages/coffeescript/.1.0.11.148kw9n++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileCoffeescript.os/npm/compileCoffeescript/node_modules/source-map/dist/test: Cannot mkdir: Not a directory
###################                                                       27.6%tar: .meteor/packages/html-tools/.1.0.5.178cl6r++os+web.browser+web.cordova/os-legacy/packages/html-tools.js.map: Cannot open: Not a directory
###################                                                       27.7%tar: .meteor/packages/html-tools/.1.0.5.178cl6r++os+web.browser+web.cordova/web.cordova/parse.js: Cannot open: Not a directory
######################                                                    31.1%tar: .meteor/packages/less/.2.5.1.1n0ne5k++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLessBatch.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/lodash/string/trimLeft.js: Cannot open: Not a directory
######################                                                    31.1%tar: .meteor/packages/less/.2.5.1.1n0ne5k++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLessBatch.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/ms/README.md: Cannot open: Not a directory
##########################                                                36.8%tar: .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cookie-signature/.npmignore: Cannot open: Not a directory
################################                                          44.9%tar: .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/json-parse-helpfulerror/node_modules/jju/test/test_stringify.js: Cannot open: Not a directory
#####################################                                     51.7%tar: .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/slide/package.json: Cannot open: Not a directory
###############################################                           65.5%tar: .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/lib: Cannot utime: Not a directory
tar: .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/request/node_modules/form-data/node_modules/combined-stream/node_modules/delayed-stream: Cannot mkdir: Not a directory
##########################################################                81.4%tar: .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/cordova-support/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/concat-map/.travis.yml: Cannot open: Not a directory
##########################################################                81.9%tar: .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/cordova-support/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/iconv-lite/encodings/tables/cp936.json: Cannot open: Not a directory
############################################################              83.5%tar: .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/ddp/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/.bin/cleancss: Cannot open: Not a directory
############################################################              84.6%tar: .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/ddp/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/core-js/modules/$.collection-strong.js: Cannot open: Not a directory
tar: .meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/isopackets/ddp/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/core-js/modules/es6.number.is-safe-integer.js: Cannot open: Not a directory
#################################################################         90.5%tar: .meteor/packages/static-html/.1.0.3.14e3sic++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileStaticHtmlBatch.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/types/definitions: Cannot mkdir: Not a directory
####################################################################      94.7%tar: .meteor/packages/stylus/.2.511.1.1gxarfy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileStylusBatch.os/npm/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel/node_modules/lodash/string/templateSettings.js: Cannot open: Not a directory
#####################################################################     96.2%tar: .meteor/packages/stylus/.2.511.1.1gxarfy++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileStylusBatch.os/npm/ecmascript-runtime/node_modules/meteor-ecmascript-runtime/node_modules/core-js/es7/index.js: Cannot open: Not a directory
######################################################################## 100.0%
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Installation failed.
jakejacobs@jakejacobs-Peppy:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when a try install Meteor in Turnkey dist:
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.2 (jessie)
Release:        8.2
Codename:       jessie

I reboot system and next time the error has gone: 
Meteor 1.2.1 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the meteor folder in your home directory first and then try again.

```
cd
rm -rf .meteor/
curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
```

Update us on what happens next.